# Active focus element display in HTML and Typescript

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Moving the selected element of the `<select>` dropdown menu list on the Top or Bottom of the list.

I am able to get the focus element of the select using :

`this.element.nativeElement.focus();`
.

But not able to find out moving the selected value to the first or last position whenever scroll is possible in Typescript.

Example :

[image: Select dropdown with names of countries]

Focused element "California" moves to the first place, every time select field is clicked and the list scrolls.

Comment: Why dont you create the list starting with "California" dynamically? if that's your selected value

Comment: Or create a pipe moving the element which is passed to it to the top

Comment: @moronator sorry just new to Angular can you please help more with pipe ?

Comment: @Niladri just to be able to display because sometimes with different browsers it gives different results during display.

Comment: @Apb what do mean by 'just to be able to display'?

Comment: @Apb you could look [here](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) for more information about pipes, but after I thought about it a little more, it doesn't seem to be the best way to go

Comment: For example If it's a long list in chrome it displays in the middle of the list whereas Firefox displays it at the last option of the list.
So to display it correctly, I want to move the selected value

Comment: Is there a way that you can provide a code example of your issue using the Code Snippet